# My Jenkins php project build is successful but Job and Build Statistics are very bad

Tags: java, php, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Here are the issues along with full report at the bottom...
I copied my project template from http://jenkins-php.org/

Though I'm new to Jenkins I configured every thing by myself but stuck at this point...

Can any one provide this file to me "Clover xml file does not exist in" and let me know where to place it... asking because even if I place a blank xml file I'm getting the same error
    1) Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/builds/13/cloverphp/clover.`enter code here`xml
    Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?

No Idea about Crap4j
    2) [CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
    Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
    Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure

Please help me understand this part
    3) [xUnit] [INFO] - Converting '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace/build/logs/junit.xml' .
    [xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.

```
4) Finished: FAILURE


Here is the Entire Report


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 53 seconds
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log with parser PHP Runtime
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
[DRY] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace
[DRY] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/builds/13/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[CRAP4J] Collecting Crap4J analysis files...
[CRAP4J] Searching for report files within build/logs/crap4j.xml
[CRAP4J] Using the new FileSetBuilder
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace/build/api to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/builds/13/htmlreports/API_Documentation
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Converting '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moneyproject/workspace/build/logs/junit.xml' .
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 188 classes in 1 packages
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the fix for this was installing libxml2-utils php5-xdebug. Now I just want avoid PHPUnit test when needed... Sounds simple but I removed all instances from code as well as GUI(DB settings) but still I'm able to see this error, also I'm unable to generate phpdoc if the project don't have test files

Answer (score 0):

Your crap4j plugin says it can not find the report files, do you see reports.xml file in the build location?